# How can I sum numbers that have over 10 digits?

Tags: c

I have this program that i want to make. There's a string that can be made from "troduplo" "duplo" "minus". A variable needs to start with 1 (c=1) and read the string. If it reads "troduplo" it triples c thats at that moment by 3 (c*=3), for "duplo" its double and for "minus" is just c=c-1. Ive made this that works well i guess with small numbers for the output, but when it gets over 10 digits it doesnt work anymore. How can i do this?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
int main(){
char string[250];
long long c=1;
scanf("%s", &string);
for(int i=0;i<strlen(string);i++){
    if(string[i]=='t'||string[i]=='T'){
        c*=3;
        i+=7;
        /*printf("%d - Troduplo\n", c);*/
        continue;
    }
    if(string[i]=='D'||string[i]=='d'){
        c*=2;
        i+=4;
        /*printf("%d - Duplo\n", c);*/
        continue;
    }
    if(string[i]=='M'||string[i]=='m'){
        c-=1;
        i+=4;
        /*printf("%d - Minus\n", c)*/;
        continue;
    }
}
printf("%d", c);
return 0;
}
```

example

input :

```
tROdUPLotrOdUplomiNuSmiNusDuPlodUPLoTRODuPLOtRodUpLodupLOdupLOmINuSMInUsduplOduPloTROdupLoTrODUpLoTRoDuPLOdUPloDUPLODupLoduplodUpLoDUPlOduplODUpLODUpLODUPLoduPLoduPloDUPLodupLoDupLODUPLodUplOdUplODUpLODuPLoDupLodUPLoduPlODuplOduPLO
```

output :

```
3645621927936
```

Comment: `c` Is a `long long`, so `printf("%d", c);` -> `printf("%lld", c);`

Comment: There's a limit for the various integer types. `long long` limit (in `<limits.h>`) is `LLONG_MAX`. If you go over that limit, you invoke **Undefined Behaviour** and *all bets are off*.

Answer (score 1):

`c` in your output example is more than 32 bits. You did define it as `long long` which is 64 bits so the program is just fine.

The problem is with the display at the end `printf("%d", c);` because `%d` is a specifier for numbers up to 32 bits only so any bigger numbers cause an overflow and you might see *-ve* numbers on the console.
To fix that, you need to write `printf` with `%ll` specifier `printf("%ll", c);`

`ll` represents `long long` and can display up to 64 bits numbers.

Comment: [C11 Standard - fprintf - 7.21.6.1(p9)](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.6.1p9) `"If a conversion specification is invalid, the behavior is undefined. If any argument is not the correct type for the corresponding conversion specification, the behavior is undefined."`